# How to get PyMongo collstats to match query instead of entire collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How do I get the stats of a collection matching only a certain query?

Here's what I have to get the stats of my collection. Can a query be added so it only gets the stats of documents that match, for example, `{"channel": channel_id}`?

```
collection_str = str(db[collection].name)
stats = db.command('collstats', collection_str)
```

Or is there a better way to do this other than collstats?

Comment: Most of the data returned by collstats would be meaningless outside of the context of an entire collection.  What values are you trying to find?

Comment: You can get a _query plan_ by applying the `explain` method on the query. The explain has various modes for various degrees of details of the query plan.

Comment: I mostly want the number of documents and total size of those documents, Joe

Comment: @prasad_ I got it with the explain method. Thank you.
```results = collection.find(query).explain()['executionStats']``` then 
```results["nReturned"]``` to get the number returned